# How to fix "subscript out of range" error in a simple code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm starting to learn how to write VBA codes with the VBA for Dummies book.
There is this code that I literally copy and paste from the book but it gives me an error.

Can you please help?

```
Sub ShowValue()

    Contents = Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A1”).Value
    MsgBox Contents

End Sub
```

Comment: Where and when is this code being called? Do you have any worksheets in the workbook? Is one of those sheets named *Sheet1*? Do you have anything in cell A1?

Comment: It's in 'Excel VBA Programming for Dummies' 3rd Edition, page 60.  Yes the only sheet I have in my workbook is Sheet1, and my cell A1 contains random digits that I just put to test the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Where and when is this code being called?" then?  I have re-read the section again, that's the beginning of the section.

Comment: I mean *Where exactly did you type that code (in what module)? And where are you calling (invoking) that macro from exactly?*

Comment: I typed the code in module 1, calling from VBE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing, since it's a simple macro, but the quotes you used (assuming what we see here is exactly what's in your Module/Sheet code) may not work with VBA.

```
Sub ShowValue()
Dim contents As String
    contents = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox (contents)
End Sub
```

As far as @KenWhite asking *where* your code is, it's either in a Worksheet, or Module.  I put the above in a Worksheet which you can see in the VBEditor window.

[image]

Comment: Good catch. I didn't notice the smart quotes.

Comment: Thank you, would there be no situation the original code above would work?  I have a suspicion that the book may be outdated.

Comment: @JosephPark the code will work, that's not the issue. It's the technical quotes you used, see how what I posted are "normal" double quotes and yours are a little more "stylized"? (Sorry, I don't know what the term is for the ones you used ...smart quotes I guess, per Ken)

Comment: I see now, now it's working.  Thanks a lot to both of you.

Comment: (@JosephPark - If this worked, you can flag it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Comment: They're called [smart quotes](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typographic-tips/smart-quotes)